# How to use rawQuery with where clause?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using WHERE clause in rawquery to retrieve data from SQLite database as follows:

```
public Cursor Return_SMS(String contact_no)
    {       
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();        
        //String[] params=new String[]{contact_no};

         Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ "SMS_TABLE_RCV"+" WHERE "+ "Phone_number " + " = " + contact_no,null);

        return c;
    }
```

But no data is retrieved. How can I get data with Phone_number equal to values I pass from an Activity in cursor as "contact_no" ?

Answer (score 7):

To get a parameter's value into the query, you have to use a [parameter token](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) like `?`:

```java
String[] params = new String[]{ contact_no };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SMS_TABLE_RCV WHERE Phone_number = ?",
                       params);
```

For a simple query like this, you wouldn't need to use `rawQuery` but could just use [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```java
String[] params = new String[]{ contact_no };
Cursor c = db.query("SMS_TABLE_RCV", null,
                    "Phone_number = ?", params,
                    null, null, null);
```

You also have to ensure that the contact number is correct, i.e., is the phone number and not some other ID number, and that it exists in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line :

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+SMS_TABLE_RCV+" WHERE "+Phone_number +" ='"+contact_no+"'" ,null);
```

instead of

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ "SMS_TABLE_RCV"+" WHERE "+ "Phone_number " + " = " + contact_no,null);
```

Comment: This will break when `contact_no` contains a quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+SMS_TABLE_RCV+" WHERE Phone_number='" + contact_no + "'",null);

if(c!=null){
 c.moveToFirst();
}
```

Comment: This will break when `contact_no` contains a quote; the returned cursor can never be `null`; and this function is not supposed to call `moveToFirst` (which is useless without checking the return value anyway).